# Ruby cucumber watir-webdriver is not identifying the object which is placed in a frame

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

Watir code which is working but add condition link is not identifying again here :(

```
require 'spec'
require 'watir'

browser = Watir::Browser.new 
pages = { "RCM Workspace Homepage" => "http://rcm-bpmt.apmoller.net/workspace/faces/jsf/workspace/workspace.xhtml" }

Given(/^that I am on the (.*?)$/) do |page|
  # Opening new browser and going to the page which is specified
  browser.goto(pages[page])

  #Maximizing the opened browser window
  browser.maximize
end

When(/^I search for (.*?)$/) do |text|
  # Ensuring that we have opened expected page only by verifying the page content 
  browser.html.include?(text).should == true 
end

Then(/^I click on Show Filters link$/) do
  #Opening the Conditions window by clicking on the show filters link 
  browser.link(:id, "portletComponentWorkList_viewNormalModeWorkList_viewPanel_showFiltersLink").click

  #Clicking on Add condition link which is placed in a frame and it opnes when I click on Show filters link
  browser.element(:id, 'portletComponentWorkList_viewNormalModeWorkList_viewPanel_conditionButton').click
end
```

HTML details:

```
<A id=portletComponentWorkList_viewNormalModeWorkList_viewPanel_conditionButton onclick="oc.ajax.jsf.doCallback('portletComponentWorkList','portletComponentWorkList:viewNormalModeWorkList:viewPanel:conditionButton');return false;" href="http://rcm-bpmt.apmoller.net/workspace/faces/jsf/workspace/workspace.xhtml#">
  Add condition
</A>
```

Comment: ohh I have added on the earlier question only. I have given most of the details and image i am not able to attach as I do not have permission now

Comment: yes it was selenium webdriver code which was recorded through selenium ide. Now I have updated with watir code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following line, Watir will look for the element anywhere *except* for in the frames.

```
browser.element(:id, 'portletComponentWorkList_viewNormalModeWorkList_viewPanel_conditionButton').click
```

Unlike other elements, you must tell Watir when an element is in a frame. This is done similar to how you would scope the search of an element to a specific element.

For example, if there is only 1 frame or your element is in the first frame, you can do (noting the addition of the `.frame`):

```
browser.frame.element(:id, 'portletComponentWorkList_viewNormalModeWorkList_viewPanel_conditionButton').click
```

If there are multiple frames, you will need to add parameters to be more specific about which frame to use. For example, if the frame has an id:

```
browser.frame(:id => 'myframe').element(:id, 'portletComponentWorkList_viewNormalModeWorkList_viewPanel_conditionButton').click
```

Comment: HI, I am getting error as below. Watir::Exception::UnknownFrameException: Unable to locate element, using {:tag_name=>["frame", "iframe"], :id=>"portletComponentWorkList:viewNormalModeWorkList:viewPanel:_id246"}     my code for this is browser.frame(:id, 'portletComponentWorkList:viewNormalModeWorkList:viewPanel:_id246').element(:id, 'portletComponentWorkList_viewNormalModeWorkList_viewPanel_conditionButton').click

Comment: Based on your other questions, is the frame also in a new window?

Comment: no it is not new window this question is different with those and in this page many frames are available and in html code it is showing table...<DIV id=portletComponentWorkList_viewNormalModeWorkList_viewPanel_conditionsPanelWorkList class=bpmWorkspaceFilterConditionsTable><TABLE class=bpmWorkspaceFiltersHeaders>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD>
<TABLE>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD><SPAN class=bpmWorkspaceH3Text>Conditions:</SPAN></TD>
<TD><SPAN id=portletComponentWorkList_viewNormalModeWorkList_viewPanel_conditionMenuRefreshPanelWorkList_Container>
<DIV id=portletComponentWorkList_viewNormalModeWorkList_viewPanel_.....

Comment: I tried with frame, href but it is not working. Details of HTML tags     <td><a onclick="oc.ajax.jsf.doCallback('portletComponentWorkList','portletComponentWorkList:viewNormalModeWorkList:viewPanel:conditionButton');return false;" id="portletComponentWorkList_viewNormalModeWorkList_viewPanel_conditionButton" href="#">Add condition</a></td>

Comment: I do not see the frame or iframe in the html you added. Can you please show the html that includes all the frames from the main page to the element you want? This is most easily seen by using your browser's developer toolbar. So that it is easier to read, please edit your question with the html rather than creating many comments.

Comment: I am not able to add HTML code as it has more lines so its not allowing me to add...is there any other way through which I can show my html code. It has 1645 lines.

Comment: It is unlikely we need ever single line. Include just enough html to reproduce the problem. The idea is to create a self-contained page and watir code that allows anyone here to reproduce your exact problem.

Comment: I am happy to hear you found a solution. Can you add an answer that shows how to fix the problem? It would be helpful for those that run into the same problem.